Calculating the Volume Enclosed by a Symmetric Surface
Problem. Calculate the volume enclosed by the surface:
$$ z^2 = (x^2 + y^2)(1 - x^2 - y^2) $$
Attempt. I have attempted to transform the equation into cylindrical coordinates. Using the transformations $ x = r \cos \theta $ and $ y = r \sin \theta $, I obtained the expression:
$$ z^2 = r^2 (1 - r^2) $$
From this, we see that for $ z^2 \geq 0 $, we must have $ |r| \leq 1 $. Because the problem is symmetric about the $ z $-axis, I should use the full range of angles in polar coordinates, i.e., $ \theta \in [0, 2\pi] $.
Since the problem is symmetric about the $ xy $-plane, I only need to compute the volume for $ z \geq 0 $ and then double the result to account for the entire volume. Thus, the integral for the volume becomes:
$$ 2 \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \int_0^{r \sqrt{1 - r^2}} dz \, r \, dr \, d\theta $$
Question. I am unsure if my steps are correct. Could someone please confirm whether my approach is accurate or if I made any mistakes? I would greatly appreciate any clarification or correction.
Thank you!

Consider using Guldin-Pappus theorem for surfaces of revolution.

Order of integration matters. Look up formulas for the volume of the region enclosed by a surface of revolution.

I believe your approach is correct and is equivalent to the solids of revolution approach. A simple trigonometric substitution will lead to a solution.

@Jean Marie: Except the  position of center of mass is not known.

@Narasimham ... If you know the equation $y=f(x)$ (here $r=f(z)=\sqrt{\frac12(1+\sqrt{1-4z^2}}$) of the curve, the coordinates of the center of mass can be computed by integration : see for example here. But I agree that these integrals are a little complicated...

Solution. If the proposed integral is correct, here is the evaluation.
\begin{equation}
2 \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{1} r^2 \sqrt{1 - r^2} \, dr \, d\theta
\end{equation}
Now, using the substitution $ r = \sin{u}, \, dr = \cos{u} \, du $:
\begin{equation}
2 \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^2{u} \, \sqrt{1 - \cos^2{u}} \, \cos{u} \, du \, d\theta
\end{equation}
This simplifies to:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (2 \sin{u} \cos{u})^2 \, du \, d\theta
\end{equation}
Which further simplifies to:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^2{2u} \, du \, d\theta = \frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} 1 - \cos{2u} \, du \, d\theta
\end{equation}
Evaluating the integral:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\pi}{2} \left[ u - \frac{1}{2} \sin{2u} \right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} = \frac{\pi^2}{4}
\end{equation}

HINT:
In cylindrical $(r-z)$ coordinates $~ r^2=x^2+y^2, $ ... letting $( a=1,b=1)$
$$ ~ b^2z^2= a^2r^2-r^4~$$
$$ \frac{b^2 ~dz}{dr}=\frac{r(a^2-2r^2)}{\sqrt{a^2-r^2}}$$
$$ dV= \pi z^2 ( dr/dz)dz $$
which can be integrated.
